# Rename foreign keys en masse on SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, sql-server-2017

I have a database that was recently migrated from Oracle to SQL Server 2017. Whoever initially setup the database set all the foreign keys to be system generated names.  In other words if I look at the foreign keys in a table they are named (`SYS_C005214`, `SYS_C005271`, `SYS_C005272`). I would prefer to have these all renamed to:

```
FK_ChildTable_childColumn_ParentTable_parentColumn
```

I would like to setup a script that will change all of the foreign keys to the approprite name. Is there a way to do this without having to go into each key to see it's definition and then renaming it by hand?

**Note**: I now realize after running Aaron Bertrand's script, I also need this for primary keys.

Comment: There isn't a magic button, but there is a script I wrote to help: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2709/script-to-rename-constraints-and-indexes-to-conform-to-a-sql-server-naming-convention/

Comment: Not sure why you want them named to nothing, I would suggest a small script that determine the definition, drop the constraint and then create a new one according to your naming standard

Comment: @Lennart Sorry, had some formatting problems with my question. I've updated it to show what I want it named to. Also the problem with your method is I have a whole database that needs this done so you're method would be incredibly time consuming.

Comment: I suggest that you skip column in name. Reason , a FK might reference  several columns. In case you have several FK between two tables, use a ordinal number to distinguish between them. Start by figuring out what info you need to retrive from the catalog, loop over this result set and drop / create

Comment: @Arons link is very usefull. I'm a bit puzzled why default values is concidered constraints in sql server, but thats a side note

Comment: @Lennart A constraint is just a fancy name for a rule. A foreign key constraint says "when you put a value here, it better exist in this other table." A primary key or unique constraint says "when you put a value here, it better be the only one." A check constraint says "when you put a value here, it better meet these criteria." A default constraint says "when you **don't** put a value here, this is the value you should use instead."

Comment: @Aron, that is sort of my point. A rule or constraint (IMO) is something that defines a line between what is permitted and what is not. A default (constraint) is something that contributes when something is missing. To me thats a different mechanism.

Comment: @Lennart I think I can disagree semantically - when you have a default constraint you're saying that when a value isn't supplied it is not permitted to be NULL, instead of NULL you should use this value. In any case, they've been named that way for ~two decades, so you'll have to air your grievance with Microsoft.

Comment: Its a side note, so we should probably agree to disagree, but not null is a constraint,  default is not (once again IMO). Though not common, it is possible to have a nullable column with a default value.

Comment: @AaronBertrand that was the answer I was looking for. Did you want to submit an answer or should I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stealing from myself](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2709/script-to-rename-constraints-and-indexes-to-conform-to-a-sql-server-naming-convention/) (please see the caveats and comments on that article):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ImplementNamingStandard
    @SELECT_Only        BIT = 1,
    @ForeignKeys        BIT = 1
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @cr CHAR(2);
    SELECT @sql = N'', @cr = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);

    DECLARE @TableLimit TINYINT, @ColumnLimit TINYINT;
    SELECT @TableLimit = 24, @ColumnLimit = 10;

    IF @ForeignKeys = 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sql = @sql + @cr + @cr + N'/* ---- Foreign Keys ---- */' + @cr;
        SELECT @sql = @sql + @cr + N'EXEC sp_rename @objname = N''' 
          + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) + '.'
          + REPLACE(name, '''', '''''') + ''', @newname = N''FK_' 
          + LEFT(REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id), '''', ''), @TableLimit) + '_' 
          + LEFT(REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id), '''', ''), @TableLimit) + ''';'
        FROM sys.foreign_keys
        WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0;
    END

    SELECT @sql;

    IF @SELECT_Only = 0 AND @sql > N''
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: Now I'm getting an error when I run these. Sp_rename is expecting @itemtype. 
    `Msg 15225, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 418 [Batch Start Line 2]
No item by the name of 'SYS_C005169' could be found in the current database 'foodb', given that @itemtype was input as '(null)'.`

Comment: @Geoff I don't think that was with a foreign key, probably something else that got scooped up but not tested. Let me simplify. Note that this can still fail if you have two foreign keys on one table that reference the same parent table, but it would be with a different error message.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting this error message.

Comment: @Geoff You'll have to let us reproduce by creating the object that contains this `SYS_C005169` constraint, and the object it points to, in a fiddle or with a full `CREATE TABLE` script. I don't think adding `, @objtype = N'object'` is going to resolve that error. Is it possible the constraint (or one of the tables) has a name that needs to be `QUOTENAME()`d? Can you run again with `@SELECT_Only = 1` and post the portion of the resulting script that contains that name?

Comment: I have a feeling it's because most of the current objects exist in a schema other than dbo.  Do I need to do anything special to rename an object in the exec statement? `EXEC sp_rename @objname = N'SYS_C005243', @newname = N'FK_FOO_FOO_FOO';`

Comment: @Geoff yes, schema name other than dbo is exactly one of the caveats I listed in the source article. Try now. Then we can work on how it fails next.

Comment: it looks like it worked. All the Foreign Key's appear to have been renamed and I the proc didn't kick out any errors. I did update the message however, i did run your script from the blog post and it looks like I need PK's and FK's renamed.